# I'm not able to open specified activity via notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase notifications to send notifications in my Android App. I want to achieve following:
When user clicks notification, activity of my choice should open and activity should perform some actions automatically which I'll define like loading specific url within webview, etc.

**What I did?**

In Firebase console, under custom data, I set key as click_action. And value as ttdemo and sent notifications.

In my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".aboutmain" />
    <activity android:name=".Timetable">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ttdemo"/>
    </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Results" />
    <activity android:name=".timetable_downloads" />
    <activity android:name=".result_downloads" />
    <activity android:name=".eforms" />
    <activity android:name=".write" />
    <activity android:name=".qpapers" />
    <activity android:name=".november2014" />
    <activity android:name=".november_2014_downloads" />
    <activity android:name=".april_2015" />
    <activity android:name=".november_2015" />
    <activity android:name=".april_2016"></activity>
</application>
```

**Current scenario:**
I'm getting notifications but Timetable activity is not opened. 
Instead, the main activity opens.

Comment: Can u show code for notification call???

Comment: can you please share the manifest file of yours ?

Comment: @Amee Joshi I haven't written notification call code. What should I write.

Comment: @Vinodh Kindly check updated post.

Comment: @AmeyBansod : Can you try launching TimeTable with intent flag as NEW_TASK. Seems there is no task present for the application when notification event is fired.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try like blow code when your `onMessageReceived` method called.

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (data.containsKey("click_action")) {
        String className = data.get("click_action");
        Class cls;
        try {
            cls = Class.forName(className);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, cls);
            //i.putExtras(extras); // put extras if you required
            context.startActivity(i);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            //means you made a wrong input in firebase console
        }           
    }
}
```

To send a notification with firebase console, put a key-value-pair as custom data like this:

```
Key: click_action
Value: <fully qualified class name of your activity>
```

Comment: Sure @Priyank Patel Trying.

Comment: Where should I call onMessageReceived ?

Comment: It's a override method of `FirebaseMessagingService` and Called when message is received. Check details in [FCM Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) and here is [Example class](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java#L41-L69)

Comment: Thanks for providing documentation. I created new service named notifications and edited manifest. Then, I wrote @Override and your code.

Comment: 2 Errors: 

1. Can not resolve symbol context. Should I write this?
2. Variable cls might not have been initialized.

Comment: context should be your application context to start activity.

Comment: Okay! I usually define intent as (classname.this, nextclassname.class). So, here, I'm defining it as Intent i = new Intent(this, cls) . But its giving me error: Variable cls might not have been initialized.

Comment: Do I need to call onMessageReceived explicitly?

Comment: No, it will called when message is received from FCM.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Modify your code according to updated answer and see.

Comment: Sure! I've tried getApplicationContext() and this instead of context. Still, its not working. Let's not give up! Coding continuously from 10 days! Day and night! Its the last step. Once, I'll be able to send notifications to specific topic users then app will be ready! Thank you so much for your support! I know we will solve it together.

Comment: No error but not working. Its opening at main activity only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass panding intent to notification in the   onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)  method of class FirebaseMessagingService

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(FirebaseMessagingService.this, MobilActivity.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
                    resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

and set to notification object as

```
Notification notification;
        notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
```

and method like

```
private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {
    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.addLine(message);
    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.growth_indus)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(AppConstants.getParamInt(AppConstants.GlobalParamEnum.NOTIFICATION_ID), notification);
}
```

Comment: What should I write instead of MobileActivity.class?

Comment: I'm getting error at following:



.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                .setContentText(message)
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(AppConstants.getParamInt(AppConstants.GlobalParamEnum.NOTIFICATION_ID), notification);

Comment: Error is Can not resolve symbol mContext and AppConstants

Comment: mContext  is context  where you write code 1- if it is Activity = than replace mContext with ActivityName.this      2. if it is fragment than  replace mContext withgetActivity()  


repalce notificationManager.notify(AppConstants.getParamInt(AppConstants.GlobalParamEnum.NOTIFICATION_ID), notification);
}          

with

notificationManager.notify(101, notification);
}

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I achieved the objective!

This solution worked perfectly for me! http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/